# what would this code be in an alternative way

Tags: java

would anyone be able to write this code in an easier way to understand

```
 private List<Passenger> getPassengersToRelease() {

        return passengerList.stream()
                .filter(user -> user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I really cant get my head around it and have been struggling on it for a few days. Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand about it? We need to know that in order not to give you yet more code you don't understand.

Comment: why don't you alter the question, and add in commentary what you think each step does?

Comment: Do you have a problem with the functional style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rough translation into an old-fashioned loop:

```
private List<Passenger> getPassengersToRelease() {
    List<Passenger> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Passenger p: passengerList()) {
        if (p.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor) {
             result.add(p);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But a better way to understand the stream-based solution is doing is to break it down:

```
// give us the passengers as a stream
passengerList.stream() 

   // remove any passengers from the stream that DO NOT have the given
   // destination floor.
   .filter(user -> user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor)

   // put the passengers that remain into a new list.
   .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

The only tricky step is the `filter(...)` step.  The stuff passed as a parameter to `filter` is a *lambda expression*.  Basically, it is an inline (unnamed) function that maps from a `Passenger` to a `boolean` value.  The `user` is the function's input variable, and the value of the expression `user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor` is its output.

So the filter works like this.  For each `Passenger` in the stream, you call the lambda expression.  This gives you either `true` or `false`.  If you get `true` you pass on the `Passenger`.  If you get `false` you drop it from the stream; i.e. it is "filtered out".

Comment: But is this an "easier way to understand"? I'm not convinced: it's just different. It would help to know the source of OP's confusion.

Comment: If OP is struggling with understanding streams, then old-fashioned loops are *another* way to express what is going on.  Yes, it would help if the OP explained the source of their confusion, but maybe this is quicker than asking for an essay.

Comment: thanks, this has helped a lot with my understanding of the expression

Answer (score 2):

Here, I think this is the simplest way to refactor code you posted above. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

```
private List<Passenger> getPassengersToRelease() {

        List<Passenger> newPassengerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Passenger user : passengerList) {
            if(user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor) {
                newPassengerList.add(user);
            }
        }
        return newPassengerList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is levereging the [Stream api](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams) available since Java 8.

In short, your code goes through a `List` of `Passenger` objects, and `.filter(user -> user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor)` only filters `Passenger` objects that have the `destinationFloor` field equal with `currentFloor` value. After the filtering, the results are collected into a `List` and returned.

Comment: thank you for the explanation I will probably need to learn lambda expressions

Comment: My pleasure, sure that would help you a lot. The article in my answer should be a good starting point, but there are countless others.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
private List<Passenger> getPassengersToRelease() 
{
    List floorPassengers;
    for( Passenger user : passengerList )
    {
        if( user.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor )
        {
            floorPassengers.add( user );
        }
    }
    return floorPassengers;
}
```

Should check the syntax, I have no compiler at hand. But basically the call translates to a for each with a condition.

Comment: ah, thanks so much, I thought it was something to do with an enhanced for loop. :-)

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer the response by @StephenC, because his answer handles the case, where `passengerList` happens to be empty.

Comment: Still, I suppose the basic idea is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it as

```
private List<Passenger> getPassengersToRelease() {
    List<Passenger> list = new ArrayList<Passenger>();

    for(Passenger passenger : passengerList){
        if(passenger.getDestinationFloor() == currentFloor){
            list.add(passenger);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I also recommend you go through [Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html).